# possessive needed? ...."to impact patients' lives by...."

Tags: possessives

Is a possessive needed on the word patients in the following mission statement? I feel it clutters the phrase somewhat and need advice.

> To meaningfully impact patients' lives by democratizing entertainment, educational tools, and social content through....

Comment: What is your alternative to including *patients'* as a possessive? Just using plural *patients* or omitting the word altogether? The former is grammatically incorrect while the latter may be a good idea depending on what you're trying to say.

Comment: The alternative would be to not have the possessive symbol on the word patients in the mission statement, if that is acceptable.  If the possessive is required, then I would include it.

Comment: It is only recently that **impact** has become a verb and some readers may dislike its use, because it became a verb in their lifetime. It used to be a noun only.  Some readers would think **meaningfully impact** to be entirely lacking in grace. What's wrong with **To improve the lives of patients....**? or **To improve the quality of life of patients...** ?

Comment: There is also the verb **to benefit**, as in **to benefit patients by ...** (another word that is both noun and verb, BTW).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To have a meaningful impact on patients' lives by**=***is more elegant***.

It also gets rid of impact as a verb and also that heavy adverb meaningfully. Yes, a possessive is needed, of course.

The lives of patients is most definitely: patients' lives. Plain and simple.

Not sure about democratize here though. Perhaps this is about making those elements more accessible or affordable?

Comment: Thank you for the input - I believe it he rewrite! It always helps but I have to ease the writer into the change.

Answer (score 1):

You're right; it's awkward.

This looks like a job for a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) (also known as an [attributive noun](https://www.aje.com/en/arc/editing-tip-attributive-nouns-or-adjective-nouns/)). As one [website](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-when-nouns-act-like-adjectives/2998821.html) explains, English often uses nouns as adjectives to modify other nouns:

> You know that an adjective modifies, describing a quality of a noun. For example, you drink a cup of hot tea. The adjective is *hot* and the noun is *tea*. What about lemon tea? *Lemon* is a noun, isn’t it? Why is it modifying tea?

So, with this in mind, we can write:

> To meaningfully impact **patient lives** by democratizing entertainment, educational tools, and social content through

You wouldn't be the first to use this solution; see, for example:

- A Corporate Responsibility To Improve [Patient Lives](http://www.celgene.com/corporate-responsibility-improve-patient-lives/)
- Biomedical Devices Improve And Extend [Patient Lives](http://www.electronicdesign.com/digital-ics/biomedical-devices-improve-and-extend-patient-lives)
- Transforming [Patient Lives](http://www.healthscape.ca/Pages/News-08212017-AllisonMassari.aspx): The Heart and Soul of Health Care

Comment: Might raise a question or two about the effect on **impatient lives**

Comment: @RonaldS - Ha ha! That's true! I'm hoping the words found after the "_through_..." would clear that up.

Comment: Thanks for validating the awkward phrase.  I think it is funny how you added the educational tools as I had provided that as an option.  The content is such a bore, but I hesitate suggesting too many changes with the writer. I will be taking your new rewrite back to gently suggest what the experts recommend. Appreciated!

Comment: The whole sentence is a frightful example of management-speak. Who is intended to understand it? What does it actually mean? @J.R. is right that 'patient lives' is used and is not wrong - grammatically - but who, apart from a bureaucrat uses such language?

Comment: @JeremyC - I agree! However, the question was about the possessive, so that's what I wrote about in my answer. (Personally, I think "To improve patient lives" would read a bit more smoothly than "To meaningfully impact...," but sometimes the powers that be simply _must_ include some key word in a mission statement.)